# Have there been any tests of e-cigs vs cigarettes?

Tags: cancer, smoking, lungs, scientific-method, tobacco

After some years of e-cigarette popularity, no labs have yet published side by side comparisons of cell cultures or mice exposed to 10 cigarettes per day, compared to 10 e-cigs.

Many labs have exposed cells to burnt vapor and 50x doses of vapor and have reported that e-cigs are dangerous.

Have there been any tests of a cigerette and an e-cigarette side by side?

If no intelligent comparative tests of ecig have been designed published in 2 years, does that reflect a negative PR campaign funded by the tobacco industry?

Comment: I've found one test here on ambient air: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23033998 so i don't understand why the who published a report discourageing e-cigs.